# button triggering function and intent at the same time. Android

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, android-intent

So i am new to android and java, and i understand that i should move between activities with intents.

```
Intent randomintent = new Intent(profile.this, loggedactivity.class);
randomintent .putString("name", namestring);
startActivity(randomintent);
```

The thing is, that i also have a function that i want it to be executed just before this intent takes the user to another activity. So my code looks something like this.

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uploadImage();
//this uploads the image, it works without the intent i added


    infosendstuff();
    //this should be executed after the image is uploaded and stores the image link to a database (also works)
   Intent randomintent = new Intent(profile.this, loggedactivity.class);
    randomintent .putString("name", namestring);
    startActivity(randomintent);        
    }
});
```

The problem seems to be the intent, when used, it ignores the other two functions above it, that upload the picture and store the link for that picture. 
The goal is to upload the picture, once done, get the link, send the link to another activity though the intent (with the bundle) and thats about it.

Comment: Please share your code for `uploadImage()` and `infosendstuff()`

Comment: It seems like your bundle is going nowhere. Have you considered using `putExtra()`?

Comment: @jake i tried but it works like that too!

Comment: But are you getting the value when you are retrieving it in another `Activity`? And please post the `uploadImage()` `infosendstuff()` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to use `AsynkTask`.

create a class, it should extend from `AsynkTask`. in `doInBackground`, upload your photos, process the response and send the link. and in `onPostExecute` method, go to the other activity.

update 1

```
class myClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = uploadPhotos();
            proccess result;
            send links;
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Intent randomintent = new Intent(profile.this, loggedactivity.class);
            randomintent .putString("name", namestring);
            startActivity(randomintent);
        }
    }
```

now you can use it like this:

```
new myClass().execute();
```

but before coding, i think you need to study more about web Connection process in android.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how i could use this method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `uploadImage()` Method does some stuff on the network and since the network request and response is done in another thread the code continue to execute and loggedactivity will show before the `uploadImage()` method is done.

So one way is that you force main thread to wait for network thread and after the network thread is done main thread continue to work but it cause the UI thread to freeze.

another way is that you should use callbacks that when the `uploadImage()` method is done some method will invoke and in that method you start your new activity. something like code below :

```
uploadImage(new ResponeListener() { 
                 @override
                 public void onDataReady(String nameString) {
                    Intent randomintent = new Intent(profile.this,loggedactivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("name", namestring);
                    startActivity(randomintent);
                 }
    }
```

Comment: That seems logical. Thanks! But do you know if i could also fit the infosendstuff(); method inside this ondataready? So it can be trigered when the image is done uploading?

Comment: yes ,but you should consider that if infosendstuff() do some works on network too the activity will show before that infosendstuff() method will complete.